# terraform aws s3 apply replication rule based on condition

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am new to terraform and I need some help.

I have replication_configuration like below and I want to apply a particular rule based on certain condition.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
    replication_configuration {
        rules {
            id = "rule1"
        }
        rules {
            id = "rule2"
        }
        rules {
            id = "rule3"
        }
    }
}
```

i want rule1 to be considered only for dev environment, rule2 for stage and rule3 for prod and I already have an environment variable which will indicate from which environment this script is being run. How can I achieve this?

Edit:
I don't want terraform to execute rule2 and rule3 in case of a dev environment, similarly, for other 2 environments.
Is there something like an if condition that I can mention before each rule  inside replication_configuration to achieve this.

Comment: What do you exactly mean with "I don't want terraform to execute rule2 and rule3"? Even if you split the 3 rules into 3 resources and apply them conditionally to the bucket, terraform would still make changes. Have you considered using 1 bucket per environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, please note there is a change in the resource from AWS provider version 4 !!!

The `replication_configuration` argument is read-only as of version 4.0 of the Terraform AWS Provider. Start using separate resource `aws_s3_bucket_replication_configuration` for configuration details.

Coming to your question .. within rule, you can enable/disable the rule based on your env.

```
variable "env" {
  description = "Env type"
  type        = string
  default = "dev"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
    replication_configuration {
        rules {
            id = "rule1"
            status = var.env == "dev" ? "Enabled" : "Disabled"
        }
        rules {
            id = "rule2"
            status = var.env == "stage" ? "Enabled" : "Disabled"
        }
        rules {
            id = "rule3"
            status = var.env == "prod" ? "Enabled" : "Disabled"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If i do that, when i ran "make plan" it says that there are differences. Say for example my environment is dev and if I don't have other 2 replication roles in disabled condition on my S3 bucket, when i run "make plan" command it doesn't match. What I want is for terraform to not run rule2 and rule3 when the environment is dev.